# Linear Algebra Matrix Orthogonality Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Let $Q$ be a matrix of the form $Q=I-2uu^T$, where $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a unit vector.

Show that $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Have you tried the problem for $n=2,3$?

Comment: Have you tried to compute $Q^T Q$?

Comment: @Saja what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
QQ^T = (I - 2uu^T)(I - 2uu^T)^T = 
(I - 2uu^T)^2 = I - 4uu^T + 4u(u^Tu)u^T
$$

Comment: Alternatively, it suffices to orthogonally diagonalize $Q$.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure where to go from there... Is the next step $QQ^T=I$? or is that not the right direction?

Comment: Yes, the point is to end up with $QQ^T=I$. Now, of $u$ is a unit (column) vector, what does $u^Tu$ look like?

Comment: Well, $u^Tu$ would give you the same as $\|u\|$ right? Which is 1?
That reduces the above equation to $QQ^T=I$.  Is that enough to prove that $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @Saja yes, it is.